# How to retrieve ArrayList from JSON object?

Tags: android

i am new to android development.
I am involving in one project,In this project my android application is communicate with Servlet Program.In Servlet i add some response message to ArrayList and convert that ArrayList to JSON and send that to Android application.

My requirement is, in android application ,How can i get ArralyList.

please help me to go forward.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON format Data inside { ..} is Object and data inside [..] is Array

Ex: if you are getting data as shown below

```
[{"A":2,
  "B":3,
   ....
  }//Json Object
 ]//JSON Array
```

You need to retrieve it by making a Json Array then going inside it to get JSON Object ,then from that you can get the JSon Data

```
 public getData(InputStream j){
 BufferedReader bf= new BufferedReader(j);
 StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
 ....
 String line=bf.readLine();
 while(line!=null)
 {sb.append(line);
 }
...
 JSONArray  js= new JsonArray(sb.toString);
 JSONObject jo=js.getJSONObject(0);
 String a= jo.getString("A");
```